# link parameter shows up as HTML instead of just the value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-2.0

When I construct the URL for a link with parameters, parameter value in link address shows up as HTML form instead of value.

This is how I am generating the link in my template:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="{% url 'facility_page' facility_id=facility.id %} "  role="button">Edit</a>
```

This is how link address shows up:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/facility/(%3FP%3Cinput%20type=%22hidden%22%20name=%22facility-0-id%22%20value=%221%22%20id=%22id_facility-0-id%22%3E%5B0-9%5D+)/
```

I was expecting the link to look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/facility/1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

urls.py

```
# path('facility/<int:facility_id>/', facility, name='facility_page'),
path('facility/<int>/', facility, name='facility_page'),
```

Comment: Your output does not match the code you say you are using to vegetate it. Where is that "input" coming firm?

Comment: that's the thing. There is no input defined for `id` field explicitly in `forms.py`. `id` being internal primary key, django generates the hidden field and that is what shows up in the link address. If i replace `facility.id` with `facility.name`, it shows up as input for name field that I have in `forms.py`. No matter what field I use, it shows up as HTML and not as the value of that field.

Comment: I uninstalled django 2.1. Installed django 2.0. changed `facility.id` to `facility.id.value`. It worked. Uninstalled django 2.0. reinstalled django 2.1. It is still working. I have no idea why it is working now as I had tried `facility.id.value` before as well and it did not work.